# Make a photo CD

Tags: software-recommendation, cd, photo

I have some photos taken with a digital camera. Which software under Ubuntu can I use to make a photo CD out of it, which can be read on standard CD/DVD players for TV sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K3b does the job! https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/kubuntu/desktopguide/C/burning-cds.html
Please note that K3b also works fine under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

[gthumb](http://live.gnome.org/gthumb) has an option for burning to cd/dvd. I am not sure if it makes a photo CD